# centos 6 yum issues installing patches

Tags: centos6, yum

```
Package 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-7.0.6.x86_64 is obsoleted by centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: /etc/oracle-release for package: initscripts-9.03.49-1.0.1.el6_7.3.x86_64
Package 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-7.0.6.x86_64 is obsoleted by centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libreport-2.0.9-25.el6.centos.i686 (updates)
           Requires: libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-25.el6.centos
           Available: libreport-filesystem-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-filesystem-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1
           Available: libreport-filesystem-2.0.9-19.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-19.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-filesystem-2.0.9-21.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-21.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-filesystem-2.0.9-21.0.1.el6_6.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-21.0.1.el6_6.1
           Available: libreport-filesystem-2.0.9-24.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-24.el6.centos
           Available: libreport-filesystem-2.0.9-24.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-24.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-filesystem-2.0.9-25.el6.centos.x86_64 (updates)
               libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-25.el6.centos
           Installing: libreport-filesystem-2.0.9-25.0.1.el6_7.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-filesystem = 2.0.9-25.0.1.el6_7
Error: Package: libreport-2.0.9-25.el6.centos.i686 (updates)
           Requires: libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-25.el6.centos
           Removing: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-21.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-21.el6.centos
           Updated By: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-25.0.1.el6_7.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-25.0.1.el6_7
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.5-20.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.5-20.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-5.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-5.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-5.0.1.el6_3.2.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-5.0.1.el6_3.2
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-19.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-19.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-21.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-21.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-21.0.1.el6_6.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-21.0.1.el6_6.1
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-24.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-24.el6.centos
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-24.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-24.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-plugin-reportuploader-2.0.9-25.el6.centos.x86_64 (updates)
               libreport-plugin-reportuploader = 2.0.9-25.el6.centos
Error: Package: libreport-2.0.9-25.el6.centos.i686 (updates)
           Requires: libreport-python = 2.0.9-25.el6.centos
           Removing: libreport-python-2.0.9-21.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-21.el6.centos
           Updated By: libreport-python-2.0.9-25.0.1.el6_7.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-25.0.1.el6_7
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.5-20.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.5-20.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-5.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-5.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-5.0.1.el6_3.2.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-5.0.1.el6_3.2
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-19.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-19.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-21.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-21.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-21.0.1.el6_6.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-21.0.1.el6_6.1
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-24.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-24.el6.centos
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-24.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-24.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-python-2.0.9-25.el6.centos.x86_64 (updates)
               libreport-python = 2.0.9-25.el6.centos
Error: Package: initscripts-9.03.49-1.0.1.el6_7.3.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
           Requires: /etc/oracle-release
           Available: 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-0.0.5.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               Not found
           Available: 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-1.0.2.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               Not found
           Available: 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-2.0.2.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               Not found
           Available: 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-3.0.2.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               Not found
           Available: 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-4.0.4.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               Not found
           Available: 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-5.0.2.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               Not found
           Available: 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-6.0.2.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               Not found
           Available: 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-7.0.5.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               Not found
           Available: 6:oraclelinux-release-6Server-7.0.6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               Not found
Error: Package: libreport-2.0.9-25.el6.centos.i686 (updates)
           Requires: libreport-compat = 2.0.9-25.el6.centos
           Removing: libreport-compat-2.0.9-21.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-21.el6.centos
           Updated By: libreport-compat-2.0.9-25.0.1.el6_7.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-25.0.1.el6_7
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-15.0.1.el6_4.1
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-19.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-19.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-21.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-21.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-21.0.1.el6_6.1.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-21.0.1.el6_6.1
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-24.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-24.el6.centos
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-24.0.1.el6.x86_64 (ol6_latest)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-24.0.1.el6
           Available: libreport-compat-2.0.9-25.el6.centos.x86_64 (updates)
               libreport-compat = 2.0.9-25.el6.centos
```

---

my cent os 6 yum  is not able to install any patches.  Can some one please advise on how to proceed. I am not sure what the issue is and how to proceed. when i do sudo yum update I get the below.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i resolved the problem in the way that i disable the oracle linux repos under */etc/yum.repos.d/*

I have this solution form an older port on the centos forum
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=46762

good luck,
duderoot

Comment: Please add more details!

Comment: Under _/etc/yum.repos.d/_ are saved the diffrent repos which your installation is for updates.  I have under my repos also the Oracle Linux enabled i.e. there was a file caled _public-yum-ol6.repo_. 
I habe disabled the repo trough deleting the file _public-yum-ol6.repo_.
After that there was now problem running _yum update_.